how to get 3-D body measurements through and image and wirte a code for it?
For an E-commerce platform, I am trying to get the T-shirt/Shirt sizes for my customers so ia m trying to devolop code for this. Which can do image processing(basically they will give an image and we will give there perfect size for them or most accurate one) and give me the right sizes for the Customers.
I tried to modify the code from GitHub, and it didn't work and i dont know what to do please help!!!

Welcome to so please read [mcve] and [ask]•

Do you have training data? Training data for this task might be photos of different people (one or more photo/angle of each person) which is your X, and their actual T-shirt size which is y. The model would be trained to predict the size y from the input X.
